# Is there a way to autofill required class / widget properties in vscode / visual studio code flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When constructing a class/widget, usually there are some properties that are required and some that are optional (using @required decorator in the class constructor).

It would be nice if vs code automatically fill in the required keys (eg. child:, onTap:) of these properties instead of just telling an error that "The parameter 'requiredParameter' is required.dart(missing_required_param)".

For example

```dart
//example of the class with constructors that we want to use
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  double price;
  String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;
  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    this.price,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });
}

//desired behavior of autocomplete / shortcut
Product(
    id: ,
    title: ,
    description: ,
)
```

Currently, what I do is I manually add the required parameter from the class documentation / vscode popup instructions (eg:

```
The parameter 'price' is required.dart(missing_required_param)
The parameter 'id' is required.dart(missing_required_param)
The parameter 'title' is required.dart(missing_required_param)
```

)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open VS Code `settings.json` and add the following:

```json
"dart.previewNewCompletionPlaceholders": true
```

EDIT 2020-01-21:

Thanks William Terrill for your comment mentioning this, this feature is no longer in preview and can be activated with the following command:

```json
"dart.insertArgumentPlaceholders": true
```

Comment: works great, but it would be cool if it would make each property in a new line, now it's all in a single line. Possible?

Comment: I think this was renamed in settings to: "dart.insertArgumentPlaceholders" : true

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VSCode, install [Dart Data Class Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hzgood.dart-data-class-generator)

1. Create a class with properties.
2. Place your cursor on the first line of the class, the constructor or
   a field.
3. Hit CTRL + . to open the quick fix dialog.
4. Choose Generate constructor.

[image]