# Is there a way to autocomplete class properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a TypeScript/VSCode setting to autocomplete class properties when initializing classes? Similar to how Dart has `insertArgumentPlaceholders` (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430064/is-there-a-way-to-autofill-required-class-widget-properties-in-vscode-visual?rq=1)). I know TypeScript has `completeFunctionCalls`, but the functionality doesn't seem to extend to classes.

Currently I'm manually writing out every property, but it's pretty cumbersome for classes with many properties; requiring constant referencing back to the class definition.

For example:

```
class User {
  id: string;
  name: string;

  public constructor(init?: Partial<User>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}

// Typing "const user = new User.." -> autocomplete/autofill to:
const user = new User({
  id: // <placeholder>,
  name: // <placeholder>,
});
```

---

#### Edit:

I'm aware about Copilot and similar extensions, they do not provide the functionality I'm asking about. My question is whether there is a built-in TypeScript feature to auto-suggest/auto-fill class properties. Copilot (and the like) suggest properties which usually don't even exist in classes, I'm curious whether there's a setting that mimics Dart's behavior.

Comment: Did you try something like this in settings.json: `"ts.previewNewCompletionPlaceholders": true` and `"ts.insertArgumentPlaceholders": true`?

Comment: @David neither of those settings seem to exist for Typescript on my end.

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome extension named `Tabnine` which supports almost every language and every IDE and editors. The AI of this extension is very strong. I recommend you to download it.

Tabnine official [site](https://www.tabnine.com/)

Tabnine extension on [visual studio code site](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TabNine.tabnine-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code you can use the [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) VS Code extension that is used to power JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense. The extension will be enabled globally therefore there will be no need of editing your VS Code settings.

Comment: how do you use this extension to auto-complete all of the keys in an object?